# Pytorch-some problems about dimension-input must have 3 dimensions, got 2

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I need to use LSTM to predict state, specificly my input is 6 dimension with 6-dimension label and output is also 6 dimension. But I come across a problem I have no way to solve.

python tell me as following:
input must have 3 dimensions, got 2

my code is as following:

class lstm(nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,output_size,num_layers):
    super(lstm,self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.LSTM(input_size,hidden_size,num_layers,batch_first=True)
    self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,output_size)

def forward(self,x):
    x,_ = self.layer1(x)
    s,b,h = x.size()
    x = x.view(s*b,h)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = x.view(s,b,-1)
    return x
```

where input_size = 6 = output_size

I have tried the following method:
the orignal training data size is [500,6](batch_size is 50)
when I reshape it to [500,1,6], the neural network can run but with large and constant loss.

I will appreciate it if someone can tell how solve it.

Comment: I think the main point is that LSTM need to get time_step, but it does not work when I put the time_step into training data

Comment: so if I understand correctly, your sequences have length of 1 only?